# Display Progressbar In Django View When downloading video (youtube-dl)

Tags: javascript, json, django, youtube-dl

I am calling 'search/' when button is clicked through ajax call. Now my question is i want to show these details **{"file_name":d['filename'],"percentage":d['_percent_str'],"speed":d['_eta_str']}** in a  progress bar while downloading in a web page.

How should i get the json response from video_progress_hook each time it is call by 'progress_hook' parameter in ydl_opts?

I want to get response in javascriprt.

Please help.

```
def search(request):

    file_name=""+str(uuid.uuid1()).split('-')[0]+".mp3"
    query=request.GET.get("query")
    ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'postprocessors': [{'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
                       'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
                       'preferredquality': '192'}],
    'outtmpl': 'media/'+file_name,
    'progress_hooks':[video_progress_hook],
    'quiet': False,
    }
    ydl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts)
    ydl.download([query])
    args={'url_link':file_name}
    return JsonResponse(args)

def video_progress_hook(d):
    args={}
    if d['status'] == 'downloading':
        args={"file_name":d['filename'],"percentage":d['_percent_str'],"speed":d['_eta_str']}
    return JsonResponse(args)
```

Answer (score 0):

In general there is no easy solution.

You need to store you request in db and return that id to the client. After that you need to create special endpoint that returns progress using request id. In your code you should update that request every n seconds.

I think a good solution could be https://github.com/czue/celery-progress